# When Others Then VS. When exception Then

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, exception

Whats the benefit of doing:

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN [error code] THEN
     [Handle Exception]
WHEN [error code1] THEN
     [Handle Exception1]
END;
```

Over this:

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN Others THEN
   IF sqlcode=[error code] THEN
     [Handle Exception]
   ELSIF sqlcode=[error code1] THEN
     [Handle Exception1]
   END IF;
END;
```

I have heard it is bad practice to use `others` the way I am demonstrating in my second example but I'm not really sure why. They are both handling the exceptions so whats the issue?

Also I've heard that I should be putting `raises` in my `when others` statements otherwise errors could be hidden from outer code blocks. Is this true?

I am very new to pl/sql so if any can expand on these point it would be very helpful.

Comment: For your first question: Because the first case, if you get [error code 2], your program still raise error, but in second case, `OTHERS` cover it so your program think you've already handle that error, and it will not raise any error.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach thanks! Thats makes a lot of sense, which is probably why you would need to re raise the excetion in the others, to ensure that it propagates up and is handled correctly else where?

Comment: At first I Do not understand your last question but in your comment I think you have the aswer for that yourself.

Comment: Yes, the worst case is something like `when others then dbms_output.put_line('Something went wrong'); end;` Then the procedure always appears to complete successfully and you only find out later that it's been failing for a week due to a corrupt index block.

Comment: I'd also add that RAISE is not ideal, since your exception will now only show up as originating from the RAISE statement, not the original line.  The syntax 'WHEN OTHERS... RAISE' should only be used if there is no alternative (i.e. when there are resources that must be freed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source code is read more often than it is written. If your code is expressive and conforms to standard it is easier for other people to understand (and "other people" includes you in six months time).

The standard approach to the exception block is to have separate WHEN clauses for specific exceptions we need to handle, and use WHEN OTHERS should we need a default handler for all other exceptions. Having code for specific exceptions under a WHEN OTHERS clause is non-conforming and unnecessary.

> "I've heard that I should be putting raises in my when others statements otherwise errors could be hid from outer code blocks? "

Generally speaking, yes. Following on from my previous point, we should write explicit handling for specific forseeable exceptions. The WHEN OTHERS clause is reserved for everything else, that is unforeseen exceptions, so it is highly unlikely that we can write a generic handler which is appropriate for all situations. It is important to re-raise the exception and allow the calling program to decide how to handle it.

In fact the same observation will often apply to defined exceptions too. It is okay to handle and suppress some exceptions (e.g. sometimes we can handle NO_DATA_FOUND with default values) but usually the calling program needs to know that an exception occurred and the called program didn't follow the expected path.

As far as handling an exception goes, the important thing is to log as much information as possible, including the real error message and pertinent variables or parameters. `No EMPLOYEE records for DEPTNO = [40]` is more useful than `Error happened`. Also `dbms_output.put_line` is not logging: in real life we need information persisted to a table or a file, because PL/SQL programs are usually run in the background, not a client, so there's no screen to output to.

Comment: Thank you very much this was very helpful!